# Install older release of tensorflow-model-server via APT

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

A few days ago, Google released a new version (`1.4.0`) of `tensorflow-model-server` package [1]. Tensorflow model server can be installed via APT [2].

I followed their installation instructions:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt stable tensorflow-model-server tensorflow-model-server-universal" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tensorflow-serving.list
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/tensorflow-serving.release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

However, I need to install the previous version (`1.3.0`). `apt-cache show tensorflow-model-server` shows only the latest version on my Ubuntu 16.04:

```
Package: tensorflow-model-server                                                                       
Version: 1.4.0                                                                                         
Architecture: all                                                                                      
Maintainer: TensorFlow Serving team                                                                    
Priority: optional                                                                                     
Section: contrib/devel                                                                                 
Filename: pool/tensorflow-model-server/t/tensorflow-model-server/tensorflow-model-server_1.4.0_all.deb 
Size: 74107364                                                                                         
SHA256: 3892446a6b0e1c2e8354df72c9ba7c662c533cc1b4477ee74872b39436892fef                               
SHA1: 87c961db61e5fc7fe6c7fc3b65e2882ceb06833d                                                         
MD5sum: f7d4d26d7bf2b5c2fcaf8e83f85ed77c                                                               
Description: TensorFlow Serving ModelServer                                                            
Description-md5: 9b7e03f5296f318009581d6e285e2f89                                                      
Homepage: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving                                                        
Built-Using: Bazel
```

Therefore, installation fails:

```
$ apt-get install tensorflow-model-server=1.3.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.3.0' for 'tensorflow-model-server' was not found
```

Is there a way to force APT to install the previous version? Or do I have to manually download the `deb` package?

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/

[2] https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/setup#installing_using_apt-get

Answer (score 1):

```
wget 'http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/pool/tensorflow-model-server/t/tensorflow-model-server/tensorflow-model-server_1.3.0_all.deb'
dpkg -i tensorflow-model-server_1.3.0_all.deb
```

You can see the versions available in https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt

Answer (score 0):

As a previous comment stated, it is perfectly working to download the version through WGET and installing it locally:

```
wget 'http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/pool/tensorflow-model-server/t/tensorflow-model-server/tensorflow-model-server_1.3.0_all.deb'
dpkg -i tensorflow-model-server_1.3.0_all.deb
```

You can also do the same inside a container.

For example, this Dockerfile will install the package in a small container

```
FROM python:3.7.13-slim-bullseye
RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget

RUN wget 'http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/pool/tensorflow-model-server/t/tensorflow-model-server/tensorflow-model-server_1.3.0_all.deb' --no-verbose
RUN apt install ./tensorflow-model-server_1.3.0_all.deb
```

You can find all the versions you need here: [releases](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/)